# How to format properties details of executable file

Tags: properties, scheme, lisp, racket, executable

The executable file has created in Distribution type, GRacket mode and an icon is added. But, right-click on the file -> Properties -> Details shows the File description as "Racket GUI application" and other default file details as shown in picture.

[image]

Here is the code I used.

```
#lang racket
(require racket/gui/base
         framework)
;;;;changed application name
(application:current-app-name "pokeball")
(define frame-width 400)
(define frame-height 300)

(define top-frame
   (new frame%
      [label "pokeball"]
      [width frame-width]
      [height frame-height]
      [alignment (list 'left 'top)]))
(send top-frame show #t)
```

Product name is still showing as racket though I changed app-name.Is it possible to format those default properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/ .
Scroll to fourth screen shot.